# Optimization for finding Leader numbers of an array

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program which finds **Leader Numbers** in an array.There are certain time constraints and the code is failing to meet them.Any possible suggestion for code optimization to meet those constrains. If possible, please provide a code snippet.

***Leader Number : An element is a leader if it is greater than all the elements to its right side***

Code:

```
static ArrayList<Integer> leaders(int arr[], int n){
        ArrayList<Integer> arrlst = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int highest_val = arr[n-1];
        arrlst.add(highest_val);
        for(int i=n-2;i>-1;i--)
        {
            if(arr[i]>=highest_val){
                highest_val = arr[i];
                arrlst.add(0, highest_val);
            }
        }
        return arrlst;
    }
```

Comment: "There are certain time constraints and the code is failing to meet them" - where is your code failing to meet these constraints? You've got to identify that bottleneck and then apply optimizations there. Primitives typically help code run faster so use those if you need performance optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the new highest at index 0, hence you always shift down all previous leaders by one.
Maybe add them at the end and reverse the list at the end instead?